# Hide paragraph element in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I need to hide an element paragraph in Query,but I want that element paragraph is hidden and retains its place,that the buttons below does not take the place of  paragraph

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add this `style="visibility:hidden;"` to the paragraph tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>p{visibility:hidden;}</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").css('visibility','hidden'); // to hide
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").css('visibility','visible'); // to show
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

You can add a style:

```
<head>
    <style>
        p{visibility:hidden;}
    </style>
</head>
```

and in js:

```
$("p").css('visibility','visible'); // to show
$("p").css('visibility','hidden'); // to hide
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "visibility" CSS property :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using visibility:hidden insted, it will hide the element visibility but not the position:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
});
```